# Dúvida com Array .JS

Tags: javascript

Alguém por favor pode me explicar esse array?
[{ fizz: 'buzz', foo: null, bar: 42 }]
Eu precisava remover o 'null' dele. Mas não to conseguindo entender o corpo dele.

Comment: remover o 'null' dele, o que significa? Substituir o valor null por um outro valor ou remover do objetos a chave cujo o valor seja null?

Answer (score 2):

**Esse é um array com um objeto dentro**. Imagina se você quisesse armazenar pessoas que têm `nome` e `idade` como propriedade, ficaria desta maneira:

```
pessoas = [ {nome: 'Ana', idade: '20'} , {nome: 'Beto', idade: '40'} , {nome: 'Caio', idade: '32'} ]
```

Caso eu quisesse excluir a idade de Beto, é só acessar o array pessoas como acessamos normalmente (*array[posição]*), e depois acessar o objeto como acessamos normalmente (*objeto.propriedade*) e rodar o comando `delete` na propriedade:

```
delete pessoas[1].idade;
```

Comment: Convém pesquisar melhor sobre a exclusão de propriedade de objetos, já que o comando "delete" é considerado lento para ser executado.